# Max 2 jump instructions to realize if statement in assembly

Tags: assembly, instructions

So, I am trying to design MISC processor that can only have two jump instructions and that can be able to realize if statements like `if(a<b)`, `if(a>b)`, `if(a!=b)`, `if(a=b)`, `if(a<=b)`, `if(a>=b)`?

I have found some processors that have JZ(jump if zero) and JCZ (jump if carry or zero) instructions but when i tried to use them to write assembly code to realize this if statements i get stuck.

How many jump instructions are needed and which? How to write if statements?

Comment: [One is enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer).

Comment: How convenient do you want it to be to do signed and unsigned comparisons?  And are you planning to implement any other instructions that could prepare inputs for branch instructions?  e.g. MIPS has some compare-and-branch instructions, but more complicated comparisons only produce an integer result in a register (where you can branch on whether it's zero or not, or combine it with other compare results with boolean ops).  http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html